# Symlinked JavaScript library versions

Tags: javascript, npm, version-control, dependency-management

**tl;dr:** How can I symlink to a particular version of a local javascript dependency?

**Background details:**

I am developing a JavaScript package and, simultaneously, a library that it uses.

For now, both are private. I don't want to publish to npmjs.

Also, note that each project lives in its own git repo. I cannot combine them into a single repo.

I know about `file:` and `link:` dependencies in package.json. The latter does most of what I want, via a simple `"mylib": "../mylib"` dependency.

Both of these projects are young and under active development. I have to assume that the library will have incompatible changes in the future. I can predict that I will have trouble if I ever need to test an older version of the child package, and don't remember which version of the library it needs.

**My question:**

I'd like the dependency from the child package to name a particular version of the library package. But this does not seem to be supported by the `link:` dependency syntax.  Is there any way to specify a version?

Note: I don't expect magic to happen if the wrong version of the library is loaded on my machine. It would be good enough if the tooling just gave an error if I tried to build the child package while the correct version of the library was not in `../mylib`